# Create a function for standard error of a population percentage in R

Tags: r, formula, standard-error, population

I am hoping to create a formula in R that I can use to calculate a standard error estimate of population percentages for various demographic factors. There are 1,045 people in my sample. My data frame is called NHIS1, and, for example, I would like to calculate the standard error for the proportion of the population which is white or Hispanic. The variables I have for WHITE and HISP are binary with 0 or 1 indicators. I calculated the population percentages with this code:

`#sum(NHIS1$WHITE)=637,nrow(NHIS1)=1045, and sum(NHIS1$HISP)=408
(sum(NHIS1$WHITE)/nrow(NHIS1))*100,
 (sum(NHIS1$HISP)/nrow(NHIS1))*100`

I thought my formula set up could look something like what's below, but I am not sure if there's a better way to set this all up so R can refer to these population proportions above without me manually plugging it in.

```
perc_SE=function(p){sqrt((p*(1–p))/1045)}
```

Thank you!

Comment: About your sample, something is missing.  637 + 408 != 1345.

Comment: Yes there are other race categories for individuals I didn't include here just for simplicity, I will edit and clarify in my posting! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a `prop.test` of a table of each column, which gives you the proportion as well as 95% confidence intervals. Just multiply these by 100 to get percentages:

```r
prop.test(table(NIHS$WHITE))
#> 
#>  1-sample proportions test with continuity correction
#> 
#> data:  table(NIHS$WHITE), null probability 0.5
#> X-squared = 3.6431, df = 1, p-value = 0.0563
#> alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.5
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  0.4993011 0.5533346
#> sample estimates:
#>         p 
#> 0.5263941
```

If you want a simple function to get the percentages for, you can do this:

```r
proportions <- function(x)
{
 a <- prop.test(table(x))
 data.frame(Proportion = 100 * a$estimate, 
            Lower_CI = 100 * a$conf.int[1], 
            Upper_CI = 100 * a$conf.int[2])
}
```

So now you can just do:

```
proportions(NIHS$WHITE)
#>   Proportion Lower_CI Upper_CI
#> p   52.63941 49.93011 55.33346
```

Comment: This is great thank you! Is there a way to isolate the standard error, or are we just able to get the confidence interval?

Comment: Unless the proportion (these range from 0 to 1) or percentage (these range from 0 to 100) is close to .5 or 50%, the confidence interval is not symmetrical because it is based on a binomial distribution. The standard deviation is appropriate for normal distributions which are symmetrical. If you want to ignore that, just use `sd(p)*sqrt((n-1)*n)` which will correct the sample standard deviation to the population standard deviation.

Comment: Yes @dcarlson that's right, although you could express the standard error in terms of log odds ratios. I suspect the OP isn't looking for that though.

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry one other question: is this calculating a 95% confidence interval?

Comment: Yes @juliah0494 - that's what the `Lower_CI` and `Upper_CI` in the results mean.